# Hide only direct text children, not element children in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a `ul` list and would like to hide all the text that is not inside an anchor. This is markup from a CMS so I can't add in additional selectors...

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="sub">
    <a href="#">link</a> not linked
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried using the following css but it doesn't work.

```
.list .sub:not(a) {
  display: none;
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9tg0g44e/

Comment: you are hiding parent so the children will also hide

Comment: I thought I was hiding everything that wasn't an "a" inside ".list .sub"

Comment: You were making it so it was displaying nothing for everything. You can just span what you want to hide. http://jsfiddle.net/9tg0g44e/1/

Comment: I can't add any html markup, because this is from a CMS...

Comment: You can use a CSS ::after Selector to add content. This may not be the answer you were looking for but check it out. http://jsfiddle.net/9tg0g44e/4/

Comment: @AndrewH: Setting `display: none` on a pseudo-element is actually the same thing as setting `content: none`, or not setting a pseudo-element at all. The content would effectively only be present in the CSS source file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.sub:not(a)` matches any element with the class `.sub` if it's not an `a` element.

Since the `.sub` here is a `li`, it's not an `a`, so that hides the `li` and all its contents.

Normally, to select any children of `.sub` that aren't `a` elements, you'd use `.sub > :not(a)` instead, but since the other text is a direct sibling of the `a` element you won't be able to target it with a selector.

Instead of using `display: none`, you can use the `visibility` property instead:

```
.list .sub {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.list .sub a {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

But note that [this will also hide the bullet](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/9tg0g44e/3) because it's part of the `li` element and cannot be targeted separately. If you need the bullet to be shown, you can [replace it with a `:before` pseudo-element](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/9tg0g44e/6), which works slightly differently from an actual list marker:

```
.list .sub {
  list-style: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.list .sub:before, .list .sub a {
  visibility: visible;
}

.list .sub:before {
  content: '\2022';
}
```

Comment: And if `li` elements are displayed `inline` and You dont want hidden content to take any space, You could add `font-size: 0` to `.sub` element (hidden) and `font-size: 14px` (or whatever) to `.sub a` element.